# Showing $f\in C^{\infty}$ and calculating $Df(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\cos(x_1^2+\dots ...+x_n^2)$. Show that $f\in C^{\infty}$ and calculate
>   $Df(x)$.

My attempt so far: I showed that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}=-\sin(x_1^2+\dots ...+ x_n^2)\cdot 2x_j$ and if I take all order partials with different directions they are continuous, I'm confused when taking over the same direction again because it will appear a sum of cosines, although it must not be a problem.

As for $Df(x)$, is it $\nabla f$? And If so, can I majorate $||Df(x)||$. I know I only need to look at $\sup_{x \in S^{n-1}}||Df(x)||$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest argument that $f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ is that $f$ is the composition of two $\mathcal C^\infty$-functions. For $Df$ we have

$$Df(x) = \big (\nabla f(x_1, \dots, x_n)\big )^\intercal = - 2\sin(x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2)\ (x_1, \dots, x_n).$$

Comment: The derivative $Df(x)$ is a $1\times n$ matrix and the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is an $n$-vector, i.e., an $n\times 1$ matrix. They are transposes of one another.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.